# Hosts.deny on FreeBSD suddenly empty?

Tags: networking, freebsd, hosts

I'm wondering why a hosts.deny file with about 600 denied IPs and ranges would sudden empty itself. Is there any reason for this to happen automatically? No one else has connected to the server to make changes according to last and auth.log.
Thanks, Tmanok.

Comment: There has been a comment at the top of `/etc/hosts.allow` saying that `hosts.deny` is no longer used/deprecated for the past 22 years.  This yields an important point to clarify.  What version of FreeBSD is this?

Comment: Well TCP Wrappers are still in use despite hosts.deny and allow being deprecated. FreeBSD 11.3 I believe. It is fairly current and was effectively using hosts.deny when I had originally added lines to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this very specific instance, I had installed features from FreeNAS for additional server management, unfortunately it included a configuration database that I was not anticipating. Every reboot clears CLI configuration, basically a backup of the configuration exists on the machine which overrites any changes to existing running system configuration. The only want to prevent this is to update some database which then updates the backup configuration.

Thanks,